# How can I apply a style to all items in a column in a tbody based on a class assigned only to the corresponding thead column in a table

Tags: html, css

Given the following :

```
    <table>
      <thead>
         <tr>
            <td class="right">Column 1</td>
            <td class="center">Column 2</td>
         </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
         <tr>
            <td>1.00</td>
            <td>ABC</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>1.00</td>
            <td>ABC</td>
         </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
```

I would like the result to work as shown in the following example, but without adding the class to each item in tbody, using the class assigned to the corresponding header column.

```css
tbody > tr > td:nth-child(1) { text-align:right; }
tbody > tr > td:nth-child(2) { text-align:center; }
```

```html
    <table>
      <thead>
         <tr>
            <td class="right">Column 1</td>
            <td class="center">Column 2</td>
         </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
         <tr>
            <td>1.00</td>
            <td>ABC</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>1.00</td>
            <td>ABC</td>
         </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your idea to work, you would need the parent selector. (There are lots of questions about it). Of course, it doesn't exist

The only workaround that I can think of is to set the posible classes for any potential column, and use them on the head

```css
thead.right1 + tbody tr > td:nth-child(1) {
  text-align: right;
  background-color: red
}
thead.right2 + tbody tr > td:nth-child(2) {
  text-align: right;
  background-color: red
}
thead.center1 + tbody > tr > td:nth-child(1) {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: yellow;
}
thead.center2 + tbody > tr > td:nth-child(2) {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead class="right1 center2">
    <tr>
      <td>Column 1</td>
      <td>Column 2</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1.00</td>
      <td>ABC</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1.00</td>
      <td>ABC</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I am trying to take another approach to this since it doesn't seem possible to do using CSS.  Having a bit of trouble with the jQuery selector tho.